# Output the input Array in C

Tags: arrays, c

My code:

```
int main()
{
    int menu[16];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("Input array value");
        scanf("\n%d", &menu[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", menu[i]);

}
```

I'm trying to ask the user for input and add it to the array and then at the end to output the whole array e.g `1,2,3,4....16`, however as of now it always returns the value `16` no matter what the user input.

Comment: You didn't put `printf("%d", menu[i]);` in a similar loop as the inputs.  So all you're going to print is the `menu` element at the last `i`.

Comment: Moreover `menu[i]` after the loop end is out of bounds.

Comment: You need to print inside a loop, otherwise you only print once.

Comment: `i` will be `16` at the end of the loop so it actually prints `menu[16]` which is **one past the end of the array** which is a buffer overrun / undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EngineerHus I do not see where you are outputting the whole array,

Comment: @VladfromMoscow im trying to output the whole array when i call the ```printf``` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run loop twice. Once for taking inputs and then for displaying all numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int menu[16];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("Input array value");
        scanf("\n%d", &menu[i]);
    }

    
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", menu[i]);
    }


}
```

Comment: You have a redundant `i = 0;` in there.

Comment: @Wyck compiler will optimize it

Comment: @Wyck yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an array index bound check failure.

```
printf("%d", menu[i]);
```

The value of `i` here is going to be 16 because you are using it after the loop. The loop terminal condition is `i == 16`. The `menu` array is only defined for index values of [0..15]. The value you see in the output is entirely random depending on the state of the execution stack. You could test this by printing instead `menu[65]` and see random data or maybe a segmentation fault.

Printing out the array to the console is the same loop as your input, but with the `printf` embedded in it instead. So your code should have 2 loops in it. One loop to gather input, and the other loop to output the input.

Comment: How can you know if the implementation uses stack?

Comment: Variables declared in the function and not using malloc() are automatic, which means they are allocated on the stack. The value '16' is printed because the linker setup the variable `i` exactly after the allocation of the `menu` variable. You can test this out by adding a variable declaration after the declaration of `menu`: `int foo=65;`. Now run the code and the value of `menu[16]` will be 65.

Comment: No. C standard does not know anything about the stack. It is up to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the comments.

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    printf("Input array value");
    scanf("\n%d", &menu[i]);
}
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%d ", menu[i]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the answer were in the answer?

Comment: @Wyck but OP did not understand comments. The answer is too trivial to gain any reputation from it.

Comment: @EngineerHus ????? I do not understand

Comment: thank you this worked

Answer (score 0):

you can add a loop at the end of your code like this

```
int main()
{
    int menu[16];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("Input array value");
        scanf("\n%d", &menu[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0;i<16;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",menu[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: DV for lack of formating

Comment: @0___________ - Assuming that a DV for formatting will translate at least into a retraction of DV for corrected formatting. :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm trying to ask the user for input and add it to the array and then at the end to output the whole array"*

Just because it has not been suggested yet...

This *can* be done using a *single* loop, or with no loops at all.
(The looping option below is an adaptation of your code with comments describing differences.)

```
//The following items, are optionally 
//defined here instead of in-line with code.
//they are used to clean up the scanf() and sprintf()  calls below
#define data  menu[0],menu[1],menu[2],menu[3],menu[4],menu[5],menu[6],menu[7],menu[8],menu[9],menu[10],menu[11],menu[12],menu[13],menu[14],menu[15]     
#define input_data  &menu[0],&menu[1],&menu[2],&menu[3],&menu[4],&menu[5],&menu[6],&menu[7],&menu[8],&menu[9],&menu[10],&menu[11],&menu[12],&menu[13],&menu[14],&menu[15] 
const char input_format[] = {"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d"};
const char format[] = {"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n"};

//it also preferred to avoid magic numbers when possible
#define ELEMENTS 16
#define MAX_LEN_INT 11

//to demonstrate both looping and sequential methods to input and output the same thing
#define USE_LOOP 1   //change to zero for doing this with no loops

int main(void)//added void
{
    int menu[ELEMENTS] = {0};
    //char buffer `output` should accommodate room for max number of 
    //characters expressed in 32bit `int` data type: `11` (from the value: `-2147483648`)
    //times count of elements to be output: ELEMENTS plus NULL terminator + punctuation.
    //This should do it:
    int size = ELEMENTS*MAX_LEN_INT+ELEMENTS + 1; 
    char output[size];//buffer for outputing final line showing user input values
    memset(output, 0, sizeof(output));
#if USE_LOOP        
    int i;
    printf("Input array values:\n");//moved outside the loop to display only once
    for(i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        printf("enter value %d:\n", i+1);//prompt user for each input value
        scanf("%d", &menu[i]);//scan value into array element
    }
#else   //Use sequential data entry   
    printf("Enter %d space delimited integer values (eg: 1 2 -45 78... 123) then <enter>:\n", ELEMENTS);
    scanf(input_format, input_data);
#endif
    //again, outside the loop to display only once
    //place all data into printable buffer
    sprintf(output, format, data);//using short representations of format specifier and data for readability
    printf("%s", output);
    
    return 0; //added return to comply with int function type.
}
```

Tested with largest possible number of digits using sequential method:
[image]